# Angular material v15 mat-select options appear at bottom of page; how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

My select options for mat-select are automatically getting placed at the bottom of the page. Meaning any elements between the dropdown and the bottom of the page will get inserted between the dropdown and its available options.
[image]

It should be above the red text, not below it. **I've seen this problem posted before on stack overflow, and the most popular answer is to add a theme. However, adding a theme did NOT fix the problem for me.**

Code:

```css
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

.flex {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.select {
  margin-left: 3px;
  width: 20%;
  border: solid 1pt lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  position: inherit
}

.option {
  margin-left: 3px;
  background-color: lightgray;

}

.opton:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="bold">WIP</div>
<div class="flex">
  <button mat-stroked-button (click)="onStop($event)" class="normal-button">Stop All</button>
  <button mat-stroked-button (click)="onRestart($event)" class="normal-button">Restart All</button>
  <button mat-stroked-button (click)="onShutdown($event)" class="normal-button">Shutdown</button>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <mat-select appearance="fill" [disableOptionCentering]="true" class="select" (selectionChange)="onChangeService($event)" placeholder="Select Service">
    <div *ngFor="let service of serviceNames">
      <mat-option value="{{service}}" class="option">{{service}}</mat-option>
    </div>
  </mat-select>
  <button mat-stroked-button (click)="onStopService($event)" class="normal-button">Stop</button>
  <button mat-stroked-button (click)="onRestartService($event)" class="normal-button">Restart</button>
  <div class="error">
    {{error}}
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out a while ago but forgot to update this question, so here's the solution that worked for me:

I had to apply the theme (the import line in the .css) in the global style (called style.css by default).